# Can't cache Image File in Android using Custom List Adapter

Tags: android, caching

I use a custom listview for my current app, everything is fine except the image caching. The images are not cache. Any one please help me to find my error in my code.

Here is my code:

The parameter URL in DownloadImage is the complete image url.

```
private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {       
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;       
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);            

            /*Write to Cache*/
            String[] imageName = URL.split("/");
            String imageFile = imageName[imageName.length-1];
            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), imageFile);
            file.createNewFile();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);  
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            bos.close();
            /*Write to Cache*/

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        return bitmap;               
    }
```

And the code OpenHttpConnection:

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
    throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;    
    }
```

Comment: i think you can easily achieve this thing from third party lib like Piccaso,Universal Image loader and volly

Comment: I got the IOException, Error Connecting.

Comment: print ex ,you written static message

Comment: `11-05 05:13:24.312: E/AndroidRuntime(30707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 05:13:24.312: E/AndroidRuntime(30707): Process: bpl.beximco.net, PID: 30707
11-05 05:13:24.312: E/AndroidRuntime(30707): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference`

Comment: its giving null pointer exception on   bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);